# How to reference SO files in AAR?

Tags: android, gradle

There are some SO files in an aar file, and I hope to use these files in my project. How should I write CMakeList.txt and build.gradle files?

#### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'example:example:1.7.11' // <--- SO file exists in this dependency
}
```

#### AAR file structure

```
│  AndroidManifest.xml
│  classes.jar
│  R.txt
│
├─arm64-v8a
├─armeabi-v7a
├─jni
│  ├─arm64-v8a
│  │      libAK.so
│  │      libAKCompat.so
│  │
│  ├─armeabi-v7a
│  │      libAK.so   <--- Suppose I need this document
│  │      libAKCompat.so
│  │
│  ├─x86
│  │      libAK.so
│  │
│  └─x86_64
│          libAK.so
│
├─x86
└─x86_64
```

#### CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(example SHARED IMPORTED)
# How to set the value of example-file
set_target_properties(example 
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${example-file}) <---

target_link_libraries(myself_ndk_module example ${log-lib})
```

Comment: what was your solution?

Comment: @StarWind0 Unfortunately, I didn't get any more elegant solutions.  The final solution is to write your own Gradle script, download the AAR file back, decompress it to a temporary directory, and reference it in CMake.

Comment: Thats actually what I ended up doing, though I didn't need to decompress it as it was automatically accessible as it was a gradle dependency. I also had mine downloaded in its own maven project, not directly to the project. Might not work for others as all this was custom build tools.